# Why dictionary comprehention gives only 3 elements

Tags: python, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

Why does this code only give three elements as output?

```
num_list1 = [6,34,-55,65,2,0,-6,77,66,55,44,33]
new_dict = {'positive' if key > 0 else 'negative' if key < 0 else 'zero': key for key in num_list1}
print(new_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'positive': 33, 'negative': -6, 'zero': 0}
```

But another record returns all elements:

```
num_list1 = [6,34,-55,65,2,0,-6,77,66,55,44,33]
new_dict = {key: 'positive' if key > 0 else 'negative' if key < 0 else 'zero' for key in num_list1}
print(new_dict)
```

Output:

```
{6: 'positive', 34: 'positive', -55: 'negative', 65: 'positive', 2: 'positive', 0: 'zero', -6: 'negative', 77: 'positive', 66: 'positive', 55: 'positive', 44: 'positive', 33: 'positive'}
```

Thanks

Comment: Because dictionaries cannot have duplicate keys. Any subsequent occurence of each of 'positive', 'negative' or 'zero' overwrites previous one.

Comment: You comprehensions are doing two completely different things. Did you expect them to produce the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because dictionaries can't have duplicate keys. Every time the previous value is overwritten by the new value, so it only saves the last positive, negative and zero values.

If you want to count positive, negative and zeroes, use this:

```py
>>> count = {}
>>> for x in num_list1:
...     count.update({'positive' if x > 0 else 'negative' if x < 0 else 'zero': count.get('positive' if x > 0 else 'negative' if x < 0 else 'zero', 0) + 1})
...
>>> count
{'positive': 10, 'negative': 2, 'zero': 1}
```

Or, with `collections.defaultdict`:

```py
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> count = defaultdict(int)
>>> for x in num_list1:
...     count['positive' if x > 0 else 'negative' if x < 0 else 'zero'] += 1
...
>>> dict(count)
{'positive': 10, 'negative': 2, 'zero': 1}
```

If you want to get all the positive, negative, and zero numbers:

```py
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> nums = defaultdict(list)
>>> for x in num_list1:
...     nums['positive' if x > 0 else 'negative' if x < 0 else 'zero'].append(x)
...
>>> dict(nums)
{'positive': [6, 34, 65, 2, 77, 66, 55, 44, 33, 2], 'negative': [-55, -6], 'zero': [0]}
```

Answer (score 1):

> another record returns all elements

Does it, actually, though?

```
>>> num_list1 = [6,34,-55,65,2,0,-6,77,66,55,44,33,2]
>>> print(len(num_list1))
13
>>> new_dict = {key: 'positive' if key > 0 else 'negative' if key < 0 else 'zero' for key in num_list1}
>>> print(len(new_dict))
12
```

Notice I added a `2` at the end. Dictionaries cannot have duplicate keys.

If you wanted to *count* the number of positive, negative, and zero elements, then use a plain for-loop and if-else statements.

```
from collections import defaultdict
data = defaultdict(int)
for x in num_list1:
   if x < 0:
     data["negative"] += 1
   elif x > 0:
     data["positive"] += 1
   else:
     data["zero"] += 1
print(data.items())  # dict_items([('positive', 10), ('negative', 2), ('zero', 1)])
```

Or, if you do want the values, you can use list-comprehension in a dictionary *literal* with **unique** keys.

```
data = {
  "positives": [(i, x) for i, x in enumerate(num_list1) if x > 0], 
  "negatives": [(i, x) for i, x in enumerate(num_list1) if x < 0], 
  "zeros": [(i, x) for i, x in enumerate(num_list1) if x == 0]
}
# {'positives': [(0, 6), (1, 34), (3, 65), (4, 2), (7, 77), (8, 66), (9, 55), (10, 44), (11, 33), (12, 2)], 'negatives': [(2, -55), (6, -6)], 'zeros': [(5, 0)]}
```

Answer (score -1):

In the second one, you just inversed key and value in your dictionnary
value : {positive, zero, negative} instead of {positive, zero, negative} : value

Just change

```
new_dict = {key: 'positive' if key > 0 else 'negative' if key < 0 else 'zero' for key in num_list1}
```

to

```
new_dict = {'positive' if key > 0 else 'negative' if key < 0 else 'zero' : key for key in num_list1}
```

First example show last positive, last zero and last negative
Second says "6 is positive, 34 is positive..."